# How to create an API and then dynamically retrieve data from and add new data to it?

Tags: web-services, api

To start off, I am extremely sorry if my question is not clear but I have very little knowledge about web services in general and the vast nature of varying available information has driven me crazy over the past few weeks. So please do bear with me.

**Summary:** I want to create a live score update app for android. (I haven't added android as a tag because I do know how to retrieve data from say twitter's JSON api.) However, like the twitter JSON api, I want to be able to add(POST maybe?) data to the Apache 7.0 service that I have running. I then want the app to be able to be able to retrieve this data that I have posted.

I had asked a more generic question earlier and I was told that I should look up some api's. I did that but I have still not been unable to make a break through.

**So my questions is:**

**Is setting up an API on my local web service the correct way to do this?**

**If so, how can I setup an API that will return JSON objects to the Android app. Also, I would need to be able to constantly update this API with new data.**

Additionally, would I also need to setup a database for all this?

Any links to well explained matter would be appreciated too.

Note: I would like to carry this out using a RESTful Web Service through Jersey and use JSON Objects during retrieval.

Again, I am sorry about my terrible knowledge with web services in general despite trying my best to research a lot. The best I could do was get my RESTful Web to respond to a GET with some pre-defined text that I had set in Eclipse.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you try to do is something like this:

There will be a match or multiple matches of some sort. Whenever a team/player scores someone (i.e. you) will use the app to update the score. People who previously subscribed to the match, will be notified and see the updated score.

Even though I'm not familiar with backends based on Java, the implementation should be fairly similar to other programming languages.

First of all a few words to [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) in general. REST is generally needed, when you need to share information between multiple devices and or users. This seems to be the case here. To implement the REST you are going to need an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) of some sorts. Within the web APIs are implemented by webservers answering to certain predefined [HTTP Requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

**Thus setting up an API on a web server is the correct way.**

Next a few words on [databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database). A database is generally needed, if you want to store information persistently. This might, or might not be what you are planning to do. If there are just going to be a few matches at the same time and you don't care about persistence of the data, you can use Java to store a collection of match objects in memory. I'm just saying it is possible, not that it is a good idea. Once your server crashes or you run out of memory due to w/e reason, data is going to be lost. (Of course within the actual implementation you want to cache data for current matches in some way and keeping objects in memory is way to do so).

**I'd recommend to use a database.**

Within the database, you can then store and access information about the matches like the score, which users subscribed, who played, etc.

[JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is just a way to represent the data/objects that will be shared between the server and the client. You can use JSON to encode request and response data/bodies.

The user has to be informed about the updated score. There are two basic ways to do so. [Push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) or [Pull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology). With pull, the client will check for updated scores after fixed intervals or actions. With push, the server will notify the client about changed scores which will cause him to update the information. Since you are planning on doing a live application and using Java anyways, push seems to be the better way to go.

Last but not least let's have a look at a possible implementation using

- Webserver (API endpoints + database)
- Administrator (keeps score updated)
- User (receives updates)

We assume that the server will respond to HTTP Requests (*POST@/api/my-endpoint*) with JSON-Objects.

**Possible flow**

1)
First the administrator creates a match

```
REQUEST
POST @ /api/matches
body: team1=someteam&team2=someotherteam
```

The server now will create a match object and store it in the database. The response will contain information about the object and whether the action was successful.

2)
The user asks for a list of matches

```
REQUEST
GET @ /api/matches/curret
```

The response will be a JSON object containing a list of current matches.

```
RESPONSE
{
    matches: [
        {id: 1, teams:...}, ...
    ]
}
```

3)
(If push)
A user subscribes to a match

```
REQUEST
GET @ /api/SOME_MATCH_ID/observe
```

The user will now be added as an observer for the match. Again, the response contains information about whether the action was successful or not.

4)
The administrator updates a score

```
REQUEST
UPDATE @ /api/SOME_MATCH_ID
body: team1scored...
```

The score now gets update on the server (in memory/database) and the user will be notified about the updated score.

5)
The user gets the updated score

```
REQUEST
GET @ /api/SOME_MATCH_ID

RESPONSE
... (Updated score in some way)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed information and yes, you did understand the question correctly. I do wish to clarify a few more things though, but mainly, how can I set-up an API? One that can be updated every time an admin posts data to it?
Thanks again.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html#first this seems to be an useful example. An in your case is nothing more than the webserver responding to certain requests. It appears that you create a webserver by passing an object for each endpoint (i.e. /match). You'd then have to create a method for each action and/or request-method (i.e. GET@/match/1 would require a method called getMatch(...)). Within the medthod you then would query your database (i.e. myDatabaseObject.query("SELECT * FROM matches WHERE ID=" + ..) and then send a response to the client (i think by returning it).

Comment: Again, thanks a lot for the detailed response. I did go through the vogella tutorial, I completed it too. I just still don't know how to post JSON data to the web service. Also, do you think asp.net would be better than jersey + eclipse for this?

Comment: I'm trying a few other things. Hopefully that would work better. I do still appreciate the detailed answer. So thank you.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response, have been busy the last few days. "JAX-RS supports the automatic creation of XML and JSON via JAXB" thus, you just return the appropriate java object in the path method - it will then be converted to a string (your JSON) and sent to the browser (or w/e) by jersey.

Comment: Since I have neither experience using jersy, nor asp, I can't answer that question for you. When developing for the web, I usually go with PHP or node.js.